# Making website type a random number

Tags: php, html, css

Hello I'm new to html and php. Just programming in general. Anyways, I'm pretty sure this should be a working code for making a random number between 1 to 6:

```
<?php
echo (rand(1,6))
?>
```

Problem is when I put it inside my php document and test it in browser it doesn't show anything really.

Comment: Did u add the semi-colon at the end of echo?

Comment: Works: http://3v4l.org/Ne2iB

Comment: **Protip:** turn on error reporting. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: @sk8 Not strictly necessary if the statement is the last inside a PHP block. Though certainly a good idea.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, But we shouldn't advice newbies to follow that way since its not a good way :)

Comment: View the page source. If you see your PHP code, then your mistake is that you're not running it through a PHP-enabled web server.

Comment: Cool! Good to learn more! =)

Comment: @user2713996 Even though your code will work on its own, it is stronlgly suggested that you close it with a semi-colon because you are including it from another file.

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ I deleted my comment (to you) because you were indeed correct, but do see what I replaced it with, to the OP and have upvoted your comment. Cheers

Comment: @deceze *"Problem is when I put it inside my php document and test it in browser it doesn't show anything really."* Code runs on its own sure, but not as an `include`. `$include="when I put it inside my php document";` ;-)

Comment: Well it does not say i have any errors in my code, but nothing pops up when i run it. Btw, where should i expect it? In left top corner or what?

Answer (score 3):

That code does work.

I'm guessing that the you do not understand how php works. You need to have a web-server/localhost set up in order to properly run php files. I suggest you use [this](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) if you are a windows guy http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Even though your code will work on its own, it is strongly suggested that you close it with a semi-colon because you are including it from another file.

Ending semi-colons are recommended most or all of the time.

A semi-colon is not required for the last line to be echo'ed.

Consider the following:

**(valid)**

```
<?php
echo "Line 1";
echo "Line 2";
```

**(invalid)**

```
<?php
echo "Line 1"
echo "Line 2"
```

**(valid)**

```
<?php
echo "Line 1"; 
echo "Line 2"
```

---

> Problem is when I put it inside my php document and test it in browser it doesn't show anything really.

### Include example:

```
<?php
include 'include_rand.php';
echo "Line under random file";
?>
```

(include_rand.php file)

```
<?php
echo (rand(1,6)) // invalid because of content below the include
?>
```

In order for it to work, you would need to add a semi-colon at the end.

```
<?php
echo (rand(1,6)); // valid for include
?>
```

---

> ### In a nutshell

The omission of a semi-colon on the last line of code is kind of saying that, it's ***awaiting further instructions***. But if something is to be strung along under it, then it will produce an error and will not proceed any further.

---

Comment: Include or not is completely irrelevant. How did you get on that horse? Also see http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php. Note: I'm not saying the OP should omit the semicolon, but it's not the problem of the code as it's shown.

Comment: @deceze Well, it's relevant to the OP. From what the question posted was about. *"Problem is when I put it inside my php document and test it in browser it doesn't show anything really."* So it's evident that the OP is trying to use the posted code inside another file as an include and will not work because of not closing the rand with a semi-colon. I merely pointing out the OP's error and giving the OP some informative options on how to achieve it.

Comment: @deceze *"but it's not the problem of the code as it's shown."* I agree with you on that 100%. True yet I was informing the OP's errors and options to achieve a successful method.

Comment: I think it's a pretty far fetched assumption that that one sentence indicates that he's using includes. I'm just reading it as "when I put this in a file ending in the extension .php". Nothing more.

Comment: @deceze You have a point there again and I agree with you. Yet it's really hard to say what's going on in the OP's head, yet alone the files he/she is working with. I guess I or we should not "assume" because as the 'ol saying goes, "If we assume, it could make an ASS out of U and ME. But in this case, it's only "ME". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To run a php script, first of all you have to install a php server(WAMP/XAMPP/) and put your php file inside the directory, WWW for WAMP and htdocs for XAMPP. And most importantly check your php syntax.

```
<?php
echo rand(1,6);
?>
```